# What is the name of asana in which Lalitha devi sit?

Tags: identification-request, yoga, lalita, asana

Consider the following picture of Lalita Devi

[image]

She sat in a particular asana. I want to know the exact name of the asana here.

What is the name of the asana in which the Lalita Tripura Sundari sit?

Comment: You mean the left leg on the right thigh posture?

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, the exact posture on the pic.

Comment: I think it's a variant of [Siddhasana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhasana). MAYBE called Ardha Siddhasana

Comment: I m not that much sure about the posture but her chair is called as the Pancha Preta Asana consisting of 5 deities.

Comment: Its like a mixture of both eka pada and padmasana.

Comment: It's probably  [lalitasana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lalitasana).